# How to return assign return message in Apiato with laravel?

Tags: php, postman, laravel-8

I am developing two API's login and registration by using APIATO-framework , i am writing return response also but i am getting all meta information along with the assigned message , but i don't want to print like that i want only assigned response only ,How to achieve this thing please help me to fix this issue...

This is what I'm getting:

[image: This is like i am getting]

`UserController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Containers\UserRegistration\UserContainer\UI\API\Controllers;

use App\Ship\Parents\Controllers\ApiController;
use App\Containers\UserRegistration\UserContainer\Models\UserContainer;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;
use JWTAuth;

class UserController extends ApiController
{
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $user = new UserContainer([
            'fullName'=> $request->input('fullName'),
            'email'=> $request->input('email'),
            'password'=> bcrypt($request->input('password')),
            'mobile'=> $request->input('mobile'),
        ]);     
        $user->save();
// This response only i want to display 
        return response()->json(['message'=>'user registered successfully']);
     }
}
```

`UserRoute.v1.public.php`

```
<?php

/**
 * @apiGroup           UserContainer
 * @apiName            UserController
 *
 * @api                {POST} /v1/postuser Endpoint title here..
 * @apiDescription     Endpoint description here..
 *
 * @apiVersion         1.0.0
 * @apiPermission      none
 *
 * @apiParam           {String}  parameters here..
 *
 * @apiSuccessExample  {json}  Success-Response:
 * HTTP/1.1 200 OK
{
  // Insert the response of the request here...
}
 */

use App\Containers\UserRegistration\UserContainer\UI\API\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Containers\UserRegistration\UserContainer\UI\API\Controllers\UserController;

Route::post('userregister', [UserController::class, 'register']);
Route::post('login', [UserController::class, 'login']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Apiato, but it seems that the value is added only with debug mode active (similar to Laravel Debugbar). [Here's the Middleware](https://github.com/apiato/apiato/blob/10.x/app/Ship/Middlewares/Http/ProfilerMiddleware.php#L21-L25) part that does it:

```
if ($response instanceof JsonResponse && app()->bound('debugbar')) {
    $profilerData = ['_profiler' => app('debugbar')->getData()];

    $response->setData($response->getData(true) + $profilerData);
}
```

Now, from the [Apiato docs](http://apiato.io/docs/core-features/profiler/#configuration) it states that it should be disabled by default. Maybe you turned it on somehow. To disable it go to your `.env` and:

```
DEBUGBAR_ENABLED=false
```

Comment: Yeah i turned off that one , now it's getting actual response ,Thank you so much @Kenny Horna